# How to use jinja2 filters to scrub dict values in ansible playbook

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook task that returns a list of dicts like this:

```
mydict:
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.1", "mac": "00324a:ac6789" }
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.2", "mac": "00324a.ac6790" }
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.3", "mac": "00:32:4a:ac:67:91" }
```

I would like to scrub the mac addresses so they all appear in the same format, something like:

```
- set_fact:
    myarp: "{{ mydict|map(attribute='mac')|ipaddr('eui48')  }}"
```

would return:

```
myarp:
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.1", "mac": "00-32-4A-AC-67-89" }
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.2", "mac": "00-32-4A-AC-67-90" }
  - { "ip": "192.168.0.3", "mac": "00-32-4A-AC-67-91" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work with `map` because this filter either only returns one specific attribute OR applies another filter to each element of the list. But you can not apply a filter to a specific attribute of each list element. I don't think there is a way to do that with the built-in filters and if there is one, it gets too unreadable.

The best you can do here is to [write a custom filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins):

```
from ansible import errors
from jinja2.filters import environmentfilter
import re

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'scrubmac': self.scrubmac
        }
    def scrubmac(*args):
        data = args[1]
        for item in data:
            mac = re.sub('[^A-z0-9]', '', item['mac'])
            item['mac'] = re.sub('(.{2})(?=.)', '\\1-', mac)
        return data
```

<sub>That's for Ansible 2. Not sure, might need some small changes for Ansible 1.</sub>

Then call it as

```
- set_fact:
    myarp: "{{ mydict | scrubmac }}"
```